Let $a<b$, can we have a form of $(a,b)$ that is closed in $S\subset\mathbb{R}$
Let $a<b$, can we have a form of $(a,b)$ that is closed in $S\subset\mathbb{R}$
I know that $(a,b)$ itself is being closed in $S=(a,b)$.
and $(a,b)$ is clopen in $S'=(a,b)\cup(b+1,b+2)$
This is kind of cheating to my question, except above examples I want some proper subset $(a,b)\subset S\subset \mathbb{R}$ that is being closed.
Thanks for any comments

Well, $(a, b)$ is a proper subset of $S'$ as you've written.

@K.Jiang Yeah, but except that one. I am thinking about could  $S$ being an interval or something else.

"or something else"? You should try to be a little more precise.

@jjagmath Thank you for your reply. 1. Can $S$ being an interval? 2. Is $(a,b)$ also closed in $S=(a,b)\cup(b+1,b+2]$., this time $(a,b)$ seems no more open to me.  3. "something else " refers to conditon for $S$ not making $(a,b)$ being closed and open

@LING Do you know what type of spaces have a nontrivial clopen subset?  $(a,b) \subset S$ is always open in $S$, so if it's closed in $S$ (your situation) then it's automatically clopen.

@BrianMoehring would you please enlighten me about non-trivial clopen set.


Yeah, but except that one. I am thinking about could $S$ be an interval...

I claim that if $S$ is an interval with the properties you state, then $S = (a, b)$. Suppose not. Then, $S$ must contain some interval of the form $(a, b')$, where $b < b'$, or some interval of the form $(a', b)$, where $a' < a$. We will consider the first case (you can show a similar result for the second). We claim that $x = b$ is a limit point of the set $(a, b)$ under the subspace topology on $S$ inherited from $\mathbb{R}$. Consider any basis element $B = S \cap (c, d)$ containing $b$. The element $\frac{1}{2} (\max\{ a, c \} + b) \ne b$, for example, is contained in $B$ and $S \cap (c, d)$ (and shows that they intersect at a point other than $b$). So, $b \in S$ is a limit point of $(a, b)$ that is not contained in $(a, b)$, meaning that $(a, b)$ cannot be closed in $S$.

If $S$ is a subset of $R$ such that $(a, b) \subset S \subset R$, then $(a, b)$ is a closed subset of $S$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ are not contained in $S$.
$a$ and $b$ are the limits of sequences in $(a, b)$ so if either of them exists in $S$, you have a sequence in $(a, b)$ with a limit point outside of $(a, b)$, meaning $(a, b)$ isn't closed.
But also any point $c>b$ will always be a distance of at least $c-b>0$ from any point in $(a,b)$, so a sequence in $(a,b)$ can't limit to it. Same for $c<a$. So $a$ and $b$ are the only points that can be limits of sequences in $(a,b)$, regardless of what $S$ is, and without them, $(a, b)$ is always closed.
Another way to think of it is that a clopen set is a connected component, and $(a, b)$ is always open, so $(a, b)$ is closed only when it is a connected component of $S$ - i.e. when there is a gap between $(a, b)$ and any other point in $S$.

@BrianMoehring yes, thanks for catching that
